# Matching a set of numbers with regex

Tags: java, regex

i have a response from an API like "1,2,23,21" also could be one single number like "3". I have this regex

```
(\\d{1,2})|(\\d{1,2}\\,\\d{1,2})*
```

and i have to validate about the pattern of the response is like "number,number,...." with one of two digit number, but my regex doesn't work with "2,3,12". I think its because the regex matchs the whole string, not only the two first numbers and then the final single number. Any idea?

I'm using Java
I tried other regex like

```
([1-9]{1,2})|([1-9]{1,2}\\,)
```

But the result is the same, works with "3" of "2,3" but not with "3,4,1" "1,23,12,1"

Answer (score 1):

Just use `\\d{1,2}` if you know that the results are single and double digit only and only want the numbers excluding the commas

Or you can use `[\\d{1,2},?]+` to capture the whole with the commas.

The reason why `(\\d{1,2})|(\\d{1,2}\\,\\d{1,2})*` is not working is because its checking for either only one number or two number separated by comma.